# SQL Inner Join not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get an SQL query that updates every bank account at once on my site.

```
UPDATE 
        bank_accounts
    SET bank_accounts.balance = bank_accounts.balance * XI.incomeX
    FROM
        bank_accounts BA
    INNER JOIN
        users XI
    ON
        BA.uid = XI.uid
```

That is the SQL
the DB looks like

```
+-----+----------+
| uid | balance  |
+-----+----------+
| 1   | 200      |
| 2   | 2200     |
| 3   | 89189    |
| 4   | 12834894 |
+-----+----------+
```

```
+-----+---------+
| uid | incomeX |
+-----+---------+
| 1   | 2       |
| 2   | .4      |
| 3   | 9000    |
| 4   | 14      |
+-----+---------+
```

The SQL query is not updating anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE 
        bank_accounts
    INNER JOIN
        users XI
    ON
        bank_accounts.uid = XI.uid
    SET bank_accounts.balance = bank_accounts.balance * XI.incomeX
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to update with a select? If so you're missing the sele

```
SET bank_accounts.balance = SELECT bank_accounts.balance * XI.incomeX
```